Why doesn't "selecting similar faces by area" work in my case?
When trying to select faces by same area, all the faces get selected instead only the similar ones.
I don't understand if I'm doing someting wrong or if the option has limitations/bugs?
See the snapshot below and file enclosed if needed.




If you have the answer, accept and upvote it or if you find it on your own, post it as the answer yourself. You should not edit the title with the answer. The title should be short and informative and summarize the content of the question. "Why could selecting similar faces by area not work?" would be a great title for this question, because that's essentially what you were asking.

Modification done!

Your object is very small, lower down the threshold:


I had never seen that option ^^'. It worked! Thank you!
